# Jquery Date-picker: Tooltip on Event Date which bind dynamicaly

Tags: php, jquery, dynamic, datepicker

I try to create dynamic tool-tip (Event base) and its done, but problem is that it display on all date, I just want to display tool-tip on Event Date.

(i.e Today is 14 feb, then it should display tooltip "valentine's day" only on 14 feb, but currently its display tooltip "valentine's day" on all date.)

Here is Static **[Jsfiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8HJU/1/)**

Here Is my **PHP + JQ Datepicker Code**

```
<div id="academic_calendar" alt="<?=$title?>">

        <?php 
            $SelectStmt = "select * from calender where isactive=1 order by id desc";
            $result=   mysql_query($SelectStmt,$conn);  
            if ($row = mysql_num_rows($result)>0) 
            {  
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
            {     
            ?>
                <li>
                    <p><strong><?=($row['title']); ?></strong><br /></p>
                </li>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var simple = "<?=($row['title']); ?>";
                    $('#academic_calendar').datepicker();
                    $(".ui-state-default").live("mouseenter", function() {
                        $(this).attr('title', simple);
                    });
                </script>
                <?
            }}
        ?>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following statement in javascript:

```
$("td[data-handler=selectDay][data-month=1] :contains(14)").attr("title", "valentines day")
```

In your example February is indexed with number 1, March with 2 and so on. Insert it in your PHP code and replace the data-month and the contains selector for each of your dates. 
Maybe you should remove the title attribute of the datepicker:

For

```
<div id="academic_calendar" title="tooltip">
```

you should write:

```
<div id="academic_calendar">
```